# Remove Lightbox on one page in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, fancybox, lightbox

I have a page where if you click on the image it opens in a lightbox now I want it to be so that if the image is clicked it goes to a separate URL.

Now you can do this with 'media link' right in Wordpress but theme used has overridden it from working. What is the best way for me to tackle this I have tested and tried and it works the way it should using media link but I need to use a custom gallery but that however eliminates media links and forces to use lightbox.

Example:

Click on an image in this page - http://wp.themedemo.co/whizz/home-full-gallery/ would open lightbox instead I want it to go to a gallery like this - http://wp.themedemo.co/whizz/home-minimal-gallery/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have this so far -

```
function whizz_enqueue_scripts() {
    // if this is not the contact page, remove the script
    if( ! is_page(2638) ){
        wp_dequeue_script( 'fancybox' );
    }
}
// adjust priority to make sure this runs after the plugins add their scripts/styles
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'whizz_enqueue_scripts', 100 );
```